# Janusgraph gremlin query to find connected components for a particular node

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph

I'm pretty new to graph database and janusgraph, I'm want to write a gremlin query to find connected components for a particular node.

For eg. I have the following nodes -

1. Person1
2. Email1
3. person2

Edges
person1->email1<-person2

So I want to find connected components in which node person1 is involved.
Also, I want to find out the number of nodes in that connected components ring, number of distict emails.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a minimial example graph in gremlify.com?

Comment: @MorKadosh Done. Please have a look.

Comment: As well as the picture, it is more helpful to provide the addV and addE steps as shown on your other post on this topic to Gremlin Users. https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/yJbMw4F06QY